# Stored Procedure in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure but it is giving me an error while executing it.

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SignupUser, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'.

My stored procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SignupUser
(
    @FirstName nvarchar(25),
    @LastName nvarchar(25),
    @Email nvarchar(50),
    @Password nvarchar(25),
    @Mobile nvarchar(20),
    @City nvarchar(25),
    @StateProvince nvarchar(25),
    @Country nvarchar(25),
    @Type nvarchar(1),
    @DateOfJoining Datetime
)
AS
    INSERT INTO User
    (
        FirstName,LastName,Email,Password,
        Mobile,City,StateProvince,Country,Type,DateOfJoining
    )
    VALUES
    (
        @FirstName,@LastName,@Email,@Password,
        @Mobile,@City,@StateProvince,@Country,@Type,@DateOfJoining
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USER is a [reserved keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) in SQL Server. Use square brackets around it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SignupUser
(
    @FirstName nvarchar(25),
    @LastName nvarchar(25),
    @Email nvarchar(50),
    @Password nvarchar(25),
    @Mobile nvarchar(20),
    @City nvarchar(25),
    @StateProvince nvarchar(25),
    @Country nvarchar(25),
    @Type nvarchar(1),
    @DateOfJoining Datetime
)
AS
    INSERT INTO [User]
    (
        FirstName,LastName,Email,Password,
        Mobile,City,StateProvince,Country,Type,DateOfJoining
    )
    VALUES
    (
        @FirstName,@LastName,@Email,@Password,
        @Mobile,@City,@StateProvince,@Country,@Type,@DateOfJoining
    )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

USER is a keyword in SQL you need to put brackets around table or column names are are keywords in SQL. Like this:

```
[USER] or [GRANT]
```